# How to create two object reference variables in seperate classes in java

Tags: java

I have a class called AgendaFunctions, a class called Main, and a class called ReadFiles. Main  has a reference variable for Agenda Functions and ReadFiles. AgendaFunctions has an array of reference variables. I have code to instantiate the array, but i need to instantiate it from ReadFiles. If I instantiate it from main, it works fine. But if i call the method from ReadFiles, it doesn't work. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException error. 
Here is the code for Main:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            ReadFiles fw = new ReadFiles(); fw.read();
            agendafunctions link = new agendafunctions();
```

AgendaFunctions:

```
    public class agendafunctions {
        int amount = 20;
        public void setamount(int data) {

        }
        static String input = "true";
        agendaitem item[] = new agendaitem[amount];
        int counter = 0;
        public void instantiate() {
                item[1] = new agendaitem();
                item[2] = new agendaitem();
                item[3] = new agendaitem();
        }
        public void createobject(String name, Boolean complete, String Comments) {
            item[counter].name = name;
            item[counter].complete = complete;
            item[counter].comments = Comments;
            counter++;
        }
```

ReadFiles:

```
    public class ReadFiles {
        public void read() throws IOException {
            agendafunctions af = new agendafunctions(); af.instantiate();
            int readitem = 1;
            BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Agenda Dev Docs/data.txt"));
            int filestoread = Integer.parseInt(data.readLine());
            while (readitem <= filestoread) {
                String name;
                String complete;
                String comments = null;
                String line;
                Boolean bc = null;
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Agenda Dev Docs/"+readitem+".txt"));
                readitem++;
                name = read.readLine();
                complete = read.readLine();
                comments = "";
                while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                    comments = comments + line;
                }
                if(complete.equals("Complete")) {
                    bc = true;
                } else if(complete.equals("Incomplete")) {
                    bc = false;
                }
                af.createobject(name, bc, comments);
            }
        }
```

If I call the method instantiate from ReadFiles, i get a NullPointerException. If I call it from Main, everything works. But further development requires me to call the method from ReadFiles. How would i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: you should post your code and stacktrace

Comment: programmers usually have an easier time understanding the problem when they look at the code, not when they read a paragraph about what the code looks like.

Comment: What line of code is the error on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this

```
    int counter = 0;
    public void instantiate() {
            item[1] = new agendaitem();
            item[2] = new agendaitem();
            item[3] = new agendaitem();
    }
    public void createobject(String name, Boolean complete, String Comments) {
        item[counter].name = name;
        item[counter].complete = complete;
        item[counter].comments = Comments;
        counter++;
    }
```

where `item` is an array with 20 indices, ie 20 elements, but your `instantiate` method only initializes elements at indices 1 through 3, missing 0 and 4 through 19.

In your `ReadFiles#read()` method, you do

```
  agendafunctions af = new agendafunctions(); af.instantiate();
```

which instantiates **one** `agendafunctions` object and calls `instantiate()` which initializes elements at indices `1`, `2`, and `3` in your `item` array.

You then loop in the `while` and call

```
  af.createobject(name, bc, comments);
```

a bunch of times on the **same** object.

The reason it fails the first time is because you haven't initialized the element in `item` at index 0. Arrays always start at `0`, not 1.

Another cause for error (which you'll see if you fix the above problem), is that if your `while` loop loops more than 3 times, you'll again get a bunch of `NullPointerException`s because `counter` keeps growing, but you aren't initializing the elements that you'll then try to access at `counter` index.

```
item[counter].name = name; // if counter is 4, you'll get NullPointerException because 
                           // the element there hasn't been initialized as 'new agendaitem();'
```

Answer (score 0):

@SotiriosDelimanolis explained why you are getting `NPE`, to fix that you just can get rid of the `instantiate()` method and add `item[counter] = new agendaitem();` as first line in your `createobject` method. Also you have to make sure your while loop does not exceed `amount`. To avoid these worries better use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html) for `agendaitem`